# Remove white space from Text-Area , Why is it there?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to understand why my `<textarea>` box contains white space when I land on the page. I have put in place an `if(empty ($_POST['textarea'])` to check if it has text before submission. I couldn't get the  `if(empty ($_POST['textarea'])` to work at first until I noticed white space in the `<textarea>`. As soon as I remove the white space the `if(empty ($_POST['textarea'])` condition works.

*Before I ever click into the textarea there's already white space* - Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Here is my code.

Text-Area:

```
echo '<div id="container">

<textarea style=width:500px; font-size:14px; height:60px;font-weight:bold; 
name= "name"  id="name" > 
</textarea>
</div>
```

I'm using jQuery to send via AJAX:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<div id="showResult"></div>

<script>

$(document).ready (function()
{
   // Focus on textarea
   $('#name').focus();   

   // '#msg' id of button
   $('#msg').on('click', function() {

      //to disable button after click
      this.disabled = true;

      // '#name' is the id value of textarea name
      var info = $('#name').val();

      $.ajax ({

         method: "POST",
         url: "actions/message_action.php",
         //pass my variables to ajax - jq here in data name:
         data: {name: info, recptid: '<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>'  
         },

         //feed the success my data to return results
         success: function(data){

            $('#data').append(status);
            $("#showResult").text(data);
            //window.alert(data);
            $('#data').val('Sent');

         }
      });

      return false;

   });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white space is generated by the way you have formatted your HTML:

```
<textarea style=width:500px; font-size:14px; height:60px;font-weight:bold; 
name= "name"  id="name" > 
</textarea>
```

This creates a space and newline in the textarea. Change your HTML to this:

```
<textarea style=width:500px; font-size:14px; height:60px;font-weight:bold; 
name= "name"  id="name" ></textarea>
```

**EDIT**

I can see that you have named your textarea `name`, which indicates to me that you might want to use a `<input type="text">` instead, since textareas are for multiline text.

Comment: Well Thanks , Thats a valuable lesson for me .

Comment: But keep in Mind, this only works initial. When you put a space in the `textarea` your check on php side will not work again. This might be wanted, it's just a reminder. :)

Comment: @eisbehr Very True , I used `if($('#content').val().trim()=='')` to make sure if spaces where inputted to check and reject

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the closing `</textarea>` tag on the same line removing the white space.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have space in between

```
<textarea style=width:500px; font-size:14px; height:60px;font-weight:bold; 
name= "name"  id="name" >// this creates space
</textarea>
```

Use

```
<textarea style=width:500px; font-size:14px; height:60px;font-weight:bold; 
name= "name"  id="name" ></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks , White-space gone and conditional statement working as it should

Answer (score 2):

Use can use `trim` to remove whitespace in your textbox, before and after possible content:

```
var info = $('#name').val().trim();
```

Comment: Very Nice Indeed , Thanks .